# QKeyEvent with ROS Rqt?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I want to get Keyboard state in Ros Rqt Plugin, I try to use QKeyEvent but it's not work. Although, when I try to use it in Qt Widgets Application, it's work.

I want to capture key state when program can do something else,

I follow that clip : [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEmnijSOJU)

My Code : [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tfycp0tVjxcFZiekxtYnkzX0E)

Thanks you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256855/qkeyevent-with-ros-rqt??/) by [Authur](https://answers.ros.org/users/29600/authur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-06-10**:
`rqt` provides a way to hook your `Qt` programs to ROS. You should be able to handle [QEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) and its child class events without any knowledge for ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Authur,

I managed to do that by using a QEventFilter on the plugin's widget object.

SamplePlugin.h:

```
class SamplePlugin : public rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
    bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event);
    ...
}
```

SamplePlugin.cpp:

```
...
void SamplePlugin::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext &context) {
     widget = new QWidget();
     ui.setupUi(widget);
     context.addWidget(widget);

     widget->installEventFilter(this);
     widget->setFocus();
     ...
}
...
bool SamplePlugin::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event) {
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        std::cout << "Key pressed!" << std::endl;
    return rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin::eventFilter(target, event);
}
...
```

I found this out on rover_gui_plugin.cpp on [link text](https://github.com/BCLab-UNM/Swarmathon-ROS/tree/master/src/rqt_rover_gui/src).

---

Originally posted by [asilvaigor](https://answers.ros.org/users/30722/asilvaigor/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0